# What is the minimum number of argument to pass in a Python thread

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a minimum number of arguments each thread can take? Currently, I have 1 thread that only take in 1 argument, port. However, when I tried to only pass in 1 argument into the thread, it will have the following error:

```
TypeError: TCPServer() argument after * must be a sequence, no int
```

My code for calling the thread:

```
serverThread = Thread(target = TCPServer, args = (port))
```

The function, TCPServer:

```
def TCPServer(serverPort):
    ##Function information here
```

However, I don't have any error message if I pass in a dummy int variable, like

```
serverThread = Thread(target = TCPServer, args = (port,123))
```

and set my TCPServer function as

```
def TCPServer(serverPort,test):
    ##Function information here
```

Test is a dummy variable that is not used in the TCPServer function.

Do I have to pass at least 2 arguments in the thread? How do I just pass 1 variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass a tuple of arguments.  A one-item tuple still has to be written with a comma.  Use `(port,)` instead of `(port)`.